# RegExp for multiple lines - matching and capturing unique output

Tags: regex

*A:Dut-C# show stats gx

`output of above command`

*A:Dut-C# show stats gy

`output of above command`

*A:Dut-C# show stats s11

`output of above command`

*A:Dut-C# show stats s12

`output of above command`

*A:Dut-C# show stats s5

`output of above command`

*A:Dut-C# show stats s1u

`output of above command`

*A:Dut-C#

---

What will be the regular expression if I want to search for the above strings in a huge file and then capture output of each interface (gx,gy,s11,s12,s5,s1u, etc.) stats?

I tried following regex but it is still not complete:

```
*/([*A-Za-z]:Dut-[a-zA-Z]{1}#\sshow stats\s(gx|gy|s11|s12|s5|s1u)|[\r])/g*
```

Couldn't figure out how to do this.

Comment: **Not Clear Enough** Do you need to capture after `status` for each line?

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked :

```
A:Dut-C#\sshow\sstats\s(\w+)[$\s\n]+([=\n:a-zA-Z0-9! \-\.]+\* indicates that the corresponding row element may have been truncated.)
```

flags : global

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/gl5aHA/5

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern seems to work. You need to look in group 1 to find the captured string.

Here is an alternative solution:

`a:dut-\w#\sshow\sstats\s(\w+)`

- Flags: global, case insensitive
- Steps: 164

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rPncdz/2)

Comment: But, will this capture the output of each command ? I'm looking for that

Comment: Do you want to capture the stats code (gx, gy, ..) as well as the following line?